# Problems charging a file

Tags: java, file, clip

I have a problem charging a simple file with:

```
public class TrisGame extends Canvas implements Runnable{
...
public static void main(String[] args){
...
}
public final void chargeSound() throws FileNotFoundException{
        try{
            File click = new File("Click.wav");
            AudioInputStream clickc = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(click);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(clickc);
            if(ASX | AC | ADX | CSX | CC | CDX | BSX | BC | BDX){

                clip.loop(1);

            }
        }
        catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
public void run(){...}
}...
```

This is the code. The output is:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   Click.wav
>   (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato)     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1181)
>     at trisgame.TrisGame.CaricaSuono(TrisGame.java:314)     at
>   trisgame.TrisGame.(TrisGame.java:146)   at
>   trisgame.TrisGame.main(TrisGame.java:154) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total
>   time: 7 seconds)

Thank you!

Comment: Well its unable to find the file you specified 'Click.wav'. Ensure the path directory to the file is correct.

Comment: @TomC The path directory is correct!

Comment: Then your best bet is to put a breakpoint on File click = new File(..); and ensure that its finding the right directory path.

Comment: @TomC Do you can write the code here?

Comment: If you need to add any other code or anything to your question you're best off editing the original and adding what you need.

Comment: Under the comments is impossible to write the code?

Comment: Make sure that click.wav is in the same folder as your project root (if you're in Eclipse).

Comment: I'm using NetBeans @TomC but Click.wav there is in my folder (/src/sounds/Click.wav)

Answer (score 0):

Well the exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException...

So, you need to check the path of the audio is correct??

Comment: I checked the patch and is correct. But I need to do the complete patch(C:/users etc...) or only the name of the file?

Comment: You need todo the whole file path including the file name

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is you will need to include the entire file path and file name when importing a file unless it is in your project directory.

Such as;

```
File click = new File( "C:\Users\(Username\Desktop\Click.wav" );
File click = new File( "src/resources/Click.wav" );
```

Comment: 'File click = new file( "/src/sounds/Click.wav" );'

Comment: Slightly compressed but you can see how I have Click.wav imported 
[IntelliJ Click.wav Import JPEG](http://s27.postimg.org/4yjbktpv7/snapshot.png)
`src/resources/sounds/Click.wav'`

Comment: _**OUTPUT**_ javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1189)
 at trisgame.TrisGame.main(TrisGame.java:320)

Comment: Okay then, what you should do now, is accept this answer as it helped solve your problem, then create a new question.